# KendoReportViewer JS upgrade issue

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to upgrade my KendoReportViewer JS file. I was using 'telerikReportViewer-10.0.16.min.js' before. Now I have upgraded it to 'telerikReportViewer-12.2.18.min.js'. After upgrading, the parameters section of reports is not showing.
I am using KendoReportDesigner for building reports. CAn anyone guide me where I am wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You can go over the [changelog](https://www.telerik.com/support/whats-new/reporting/release-history) on their site or ask on the Kendo forums what changes were made between these two versions.

Answer (score 0):

The report viewer and report server have to be identical in version or at least  close.  I have asked Telerik support about this before.

Comment: The report server also contains updated assemblies. The only difference is I haven't created created the .trdp files from scratch. Instead, I only upgraded the .trdx file using 'Save As' feature by opening it in latest Kendo Report Designer.

Comment: @ArslanIqbal WIth the older designer you could save the report and inspect the XML.  You can no longer do that with the new designer.  So the report works, you just cannot see the parameters pane?

Comment: I created the xml file using Report Designer R3 2018 and I can edit it and everything's working fine. The only issue is I am not able to see the parameters pane.